# Redux and data normalization – performance question

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Data normalization is usually recommended with Redux in order to avoid unnecessary re-rendering of the components.

For instance, if you have blog posts and comments, all the nested comments need to be stored in a single flat array at the root of the store. It seems to me that while solving the perf issue with re-rendering, it introduces another perf issue when adding or updating comments since we need to copy the whole array in that case (in order to satisfy immutability requirement). Since we can easily have tens of thousands comments, it will become a performance problem pretty quickly. Am I missing something or this is actually the case?

Answer (score 1):

When you copy the `array` of comments you are creating what's called a "shallow copy".  The `array` itself is totally new, but each comment `object` inside the array is **not** a new `object` - it is a reference to the existing `object`.  Only the one comment which you are editing will have a new comment `object`.  Because of this, the performance impact of copying the `array` is minimal.

Comment: But you still have to copy the array of references - isn't it going to become an issue if you have to copy an array with thousands of references every time a comment is added?

Comment: I'm not a performance expert but I don't think it's a big deal.  The bigger deal is to avoid  updating the comments state repeatedly.  If you were implementing a comment edit form, you would not want to update the redux store with every keystroke. You would use a local component state to store the temporary state of the comment and then dispatch your redux action when the users clicks the submit button.